# Maven build checking for eclipse warnings

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Is it possible to create a maven build, where eclipse warnings lead to build failure, but the application is still built with the default compiler?

It would be nice to have a simple way to enforce keeping the eclipse workspace "Java Problem" warning free. Using our CI build to identify such issues seems like a good solution.

It is very well described [here by Andy Balaam](https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2016/12/23/setting-up-a-sane-maven-project/) how one could create such a maven project using the maven-compiler-plugin, where javac warnings mark the build as failure:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This works well with javac warnings, but the eclipse compiler seems to have slightly different warnings. At least I see different warnings appearing in eclipse. For example unused fields are marked by eclipse as a Java problem by default, but there is no javac warning appearing with `-xlint:all`.

Is there a way to make the maven build fail, whenever an eclipse warning ("Java Problem") is present?

Comment: See https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_batch_compiler.htm

Comment: I would suggest to check for [checkstyle](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/) or you could check for [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/) depending if it's an open source project or corporate work.

Comment: @khmarbaise You might use these tools in addition, but as a replacement they do not make sense, even though there are some overlaps here. Regarding warnings, `javac` is behind ecj by far. Anyway, that's not what was asked for.